# Сползает блок Div

Tags: html, css

Всем привет! Есть такая разметка

```css
body { /* Только для демонстрации проблемы */
  width: 516px;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

.cat_block{
  float: left; 
  width: 150px; 
  margin-right: 20px; 
  border: 1px solid #cccccc; 
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="cat_block">
  Первый блок<br>
  Первый блок<br>
  Первый блок<br>
  Первый блок<br>
  Первый блок<br>
</div>
<div class="cat_block">
  Второй блок<br>
  Второй блок<br>
  Второй блок<br>
</div>
<div class="cat_block">
  Третий блок<br>
  Третий блок<br>
  Третий блок<br>
  Третий блок<br>
</div>
<div class="cat_block">
  Четвёртый блок<br>
  Четвёртый блок<br>
  Четвёртый блок<br>
</div>
```

Почему последний четвертый блок находиться не под первым (Блок МУ по районам). ПринтСкрин ниже.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вроде бы прописал свойство overflow:hidden;

Comment: Если вам нужно чтоб в один ряд выводило только 3 блока, то почему бы не использовать `<table>` ?

Comment: Да я вот всю жизнь делал через table, а потом начитался что плохо индексируются и еще куча недостатков, поэтому хочется как то через div сделать

Comment: Значит вам нужен еще один div , и внутри его размещать по три блока

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В комментарии вам правильно подсказали, если у вас фиксированное количество блоков в ряду - нужно ввести еще один блок `div` для каждого ряда для объединения блоков.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qg3vz9z4/1/)

```
<div class="threeBlocks">
    <div class="cat_block">
    .....<br/>
    .....<br/>
    .....<br/>
    .....<br/>
    .....
    </div>
    <div class="cat_block">
    .....<br/>
    .....
    </div>
    <div class="cat_block">
    .....<br/>
    .....<br/>
    .....
    </div>
</div>
<div class="threeBlocks">
    <div class="cat_block">
    .....<br/>
    .....
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: К сожалению не работает. Т.к. Дивы у меня могут быть разной высотой! И у меня не фикисрованно может быть три!

Comment: @duddeniska Посмотрите JS fiddle. Див-ы разной высоты и прекрасно работает. На забудьте для наружнего блока тоже проставить свойство float:left.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте просто для четырех блоков (без дополнительных обертывающих)

```
.cat_block{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Oveflow hidden надо вешать на контейнер. Но при динамическом числе блоков так не получится. А при фиксированном можно было бы добавить `clear:left` каждому третьему.

В твоём случае поможет `display:inline-block`, но обрати внимание на способ закрытия и открытия соседних тегов. Если сделать не так, то там окажется текстовый пробел и ширина не сойдётся.

```css
body { /* Только для демонстрации проблемы */
  width: 516px;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

.cat_block{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 150px; 
  margin-right: 20px; 
  border: 1px solid #cccccc; 
}
```

```html
<div class="cat_block">
  Первый блок<br>
  Первый блок<br>
  Первый блок<br>
  Первый блок<br>
  Первый блок<br>
</div><div class="cat_block">
  Второй блок<br>
  Второй блок<br>
  Второй блок<br>
</div><div class="cat_block">
  Третий блок<br>
  Третий блок<br>
  Третий блок<br>
  Третий блок<br>
</div><div class="cat_block">
  Четвёртый блок<br>
  Четвёртый блок<br>
  Четвёртый блок<br>
</div>
```

Ещё один вариант - использовать flexbox. Поддержку браузеров можно посмотреть на [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox). Я написал вариант без префиксов - все современные браузеры и Опера 12 его съедят. Необходимость добавления префиксов и старого синтаксиса оцени сам по caniuse.

```css
body { /* Только для демонстрации проблемы */
  width: 516px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-start; /* Если не указать, то растянутся по высоте */
}

.cat_block{
  width: 150px; 
  margin-right: 20px; 
  border: 1px solid #cccccc; 
}
```

```html
<div class="cat_block">
  Первый блок<br>
  Первый блок<br>
  Первый блок<br>
  Первый блок<br>
  Первый блок<br>
</div>
<div class="cat_block">
  Второй блок<br>
  Второй блок<br>
  Второй блок<br>
</div>
<div class="cat_block">
  Третий блок<br>
  Третий блок<br>
  Третий блок<br>
  Третий блок<br>
</div>
<div class="cat_block">
  Четвёртый блок<br>
  Четвёртый блок<br>
  Четвёртый блок<br>
</div>
```

Если нужно ровно 3 блока в строку, то можно сделать так:

```css
body { /* Только для демонстрации проблемы */
  width: 516px;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

.cat_block {
  float: left; 
  width: 150px; 
  margin-right: 20px; 
  border: 1px solid #cccccc; 
}

.cat_block:nth-child(3n+1) {
  clear: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="cat_block">
  Первый блок<br>
  Первый блок<br>
  Первый блок<br>
  Первый блок<br>
  Первый блок<br>
</div>
<div class="cat_block">
  Второй блок<br>
  Второй блок<br>
  Второй блок<br>
</div>
<div class="cat_block">
  Третий блок<br>
  Третий блок<br>
  Третий блок<br>
  Третий блок<br>
</div>
<div class="cat_block">
  Четвёртый блок<br>
  Четвёртый блок<br>
  Четвёртый блок<br>
</div>
```